# Getting parent class' name using Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

How can I get the name of the parent class of some class using Reflection?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Like so:

```
typeof(Typ).BaseType.Name
```

Comment: In vb `TypeOf(Typ).GetType().BaseType.Name`

Comment: @Alexandre I don't think that that's correct; `TypeOf` doesn't return a value, it's used as a comparator. Eg `If TypeOf Typ Is Object Then ...`. The VB equivalent of C#'s `typeof(Typ)` is `GetType(Typ)`. Or you can use Type.GetType("NameOfTyp")`. All overly confusing, I think.

Answer (score 39):

I came to this question seeking the class which declares a nested class, which is the DeclaringType.

```
this.GetType().DeclaringType.Name
```

Maybe not what the OP asked, but maybe someone else comes here with the same search criteria as me. ;-)

Comment: This is also the right answer if you want the containing class for an `enum`. Again, not what the OP asked, but exactly what I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 19):

```
obj.GetType().BaseType.Name
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
string baseclassName = typeof(MyClass).BaseType.Name;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        Type baseType = type.BaseType;
        string baseName = baseType.Name;
```

Answer (score 5):

The question above is asking about the Parent Type, which can be retrieved using:

`yourRefVar.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType.Name`

Answer (score 2):

Currently in .NET Core, BaseType is not available, you can retrieve it by:

```
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().BaseType
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add some more details, in case you need to find the ultimate parent class of your class, this code could help. I consider that I don't know whether the `type` is a class or an interface.

```
do
{
    if (type.IsInterface)
        if (type.BaseType == null)
            break;

    if (type.IsClass)
        if (type.BaseType == typeof(object))
            break;

    type = type.BaseType;

} while (true);

string ultimateBaseTypeName = type.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for that (based on [Oliamster's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305404/12136394)):

```cs
do
{
    if (type.DeclaringType is null)
        break;

    type = type.DeclaringType;
}
while (true);

string ultimateBaseTypeName = type.Name;
```

So for type `A.B.C` it will return `A`.