# Is there a agnostic way to cast a derived class back to its base class without specifying the base?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, casting

Since in C#, classes can only be derived from a single class, is there a way to do something like:

```
class Control
{}

class Button : Control
{}

class Slider : Control
{}

Button b = new Button();
Slider s = new Slider();

var base = (base) b;
var base2 = CastToBase(s);
```

I am curious about this because I want to be able to do this without knowing their base class, for instance at runtime.

Comment: Don't believe so. You'd always end up at System.Object.

Comment: You should see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524562/to-get-parent-class-using-reflection-on-c-sharp which might answer your question.

Comment: Also, do you mean built into the language or something you could write?

Comment: What use is a cast unless you know what you're casting to?

Comment: @Muzz: built into the language like `this` and `base` keywords.

Comment: @spender: It's useful when you wanna do some dynamic stuff at runtime like inspect all the properties of the base class of a value and show them, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can only be derived from a single class, but that doesn't mean that any base class hasn't also been derived from another base class unless it's `System.Object`.  If you could determine the Base class (you can using reflection) and you cast it as the base class (you might be able to using reflection), what would you gain at run-time?

If you are attempting to gain access to a base class method/property not available in the derived class, there is probably a very good reason it's not available in the derived type.  If you are determined to do that, I don't think you need to cast it, you can simply get the base type, find the method/properties of the base type and invoke them on the derived type.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BaseTypetest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseClass2 class2 = new BaseClass2();
            Console.WriteLine(class2.Value.ToString());
            Type baseClass = class2.GetType().BaseType;
            Console.WriteLine(baseClass.FullName);
            PropertyInfo info = baseClass.GetProperty("Value");
            if (info != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(info.GetValue(class2, null).ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass1 : Object
    {
        public BaseClass1()
        {
            this.Value = 1;
        }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseClass2 : BaseClass1
    {
        public BaseClass2()
        {
            this.Value = 2;
        }
        public new int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
2
BaseTypetest.BaseClass1
1
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I meant the immediate base class of a type.

Comment: You haven't mentioned WHY you need to cast it.  Answering WHY will get you more answers and probably the answer you need without casting the class.

Comment: Yes I didn't because I thought you saw my last added comment to the question: "It's useful when you wanna do some dynamic stuff at runtime like inspect all the properties of the base class of a value and show them, etc." Basically need to inspect the base class of a value at runtime.

Comment: So you don't need to cast it to do that.  You need the base type, a list methodinfo/propertyinfo of the base type, and execute them on the derived type.  Methodinfo/propertyinfo are of the base type so when executed on the derived type they actually execute on the base type (I'm pretty sure).

Answer (score 2):

You are able to get the `BaseType` of an object via reflection:

```
something.GetType().BaseType
```

With that `Type` object, you could cast it dynamically at runtime.

However, I strongly advise against that. It will slow down your code, there is no compiler check for the type either.

If you need this to put it in an `IList<BaseType>`, you can already do that.

Comment: Thanks, after getting that type, how do you cast it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the problem that you are attempting to solve (for example, prevent all controls from accepting user input, which is handled differently depending on the control implementation), your best bet may be to create and implement interfaces for the desired unit of work.

We use interfaces extensively in our applications specifically so that we don't have to worry about how a given control implements the functionality that we require from it. It requires a little more configuration up front, but is well worth the effort in the long run.