# Restricting arguments to less or equally derived types

Tags: c#

I have the a "Transfer" method that is designed to take an amount from one pile to another. Now obviously you don't want to be transferring things into piles of the wrong type.

```
using System.Collections;

public class Pile
{
    public int Amount;

    public int GetAmount { get { return Amount; } }
}

public static class PileHelper
{
    public static void Transfer<T>(this T from, T to, int amount) where T : Pile
    {
        from.Amount -= amount;
        to.Amount += amount;
        //Debug.Log(amount + " " + typeof(T).ToString() + " sent.");
    }
}

//example
public class Meat : Pile
{
}

public class Fruit : Pile
{
}

public class Example
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var meat = new Meat();
        var fruit = new Fruit();
        var pile = new Pile();

        meat.Transfer(pile, 1); //correctly compiles, can transfer to a less derived type
        meat.Transfer(fruit,1); //correctly does not compile, different types
        pile.Transfer(meat, 1); //incorrectly compiles, should not compile because transfering to a more derived type
    }
}
```

I want to set up my generic arguments in such a way that "pile" cannot transfer to "meat". The type T is defined by the arguments, and when one is derived from the other it takes the least derived. I want to force it to take the first argument and give a compiler error if the second argument is invalid.

One solution I can think of is this, but it seems a bit crude. (haven't tested it) I would prefer compiler errors rather than runtime exceptions.

```
public static void Transfer<T>(this T from, Pile to, int amount) where T : Pile
    {
        if(!(to is T)){ throw new Exception();}
        from.Amount -= amount;
        to.Amount += amount;
        //Debug.Log(amount + " " + typeof(T).ToString() + " sent.");
    }
```

I'm going to have to sadly exclude covariance and contravariance as Unity3D has all sorts of runtime errors when using them. Its a know problem about passing complex pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have generic of 2 parameters to set relationship between them. I think you are looking for class of the first argument deriving (or equal) from class of second as restriction:

```
public static void Transfer<T,Y>(this T from, Y to, int amount) 
   where T : Y     // T is same or derived from Y
   where Y : Pile  // Y is Pile, hence T is Pile too.
{
    from.Amount -= amount;
    to.Amount += amount;
    //Debug.Log(amount + " " + typeof(T).ToString() + " sent.");
}
```

Which fails both cases you want to fail.

Comment: Of course, thank you so much. After staring at the same problem for too long its sometimes hard to see the simple solution.

Comment: Aaaaaaands it doesn't compile in Unity.  Apparently its not smart enough to realize that T is indirectly constrained to Pile and thus can't find its ".Amount"

Comment: @pseudoabdul can Unity3d handle `where T : Pile,Y` (instead of just `where T: Y`)? If not maybe add interface and `where T: IPile, Y` ?

Answer (score -1):

You could also try Reflection [as describe in the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524562/getting-parent-class-name-using-reflection) but in the end you will have to throw a (custom) Exception and let the caller handle the situation - it is a public API after all.

Comment: This answer does not suggest producing an outcome different than the question owner's own possible solution, and the owner's solution is cleaner. Neither solution solves the problem of making it compile time, which Alexei's answer achieves.