# C# interface which mimics static list of types

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a serialization utility method which, as one of the parameters, takes a `List<Type>` as one of the parameters.

When I design a class which I intend on using with this method, I am required to know which types I am using, and all other types of which the types I am using may use.

For example, imagine I have 3 classes:

```
public class Foo 
{
 // some members
}

public class Bar : Foo 
{
// additional members
}

public class Barf 
{
// more members
  public Bar item { get; set; }
}
```

I am wanting to take responsibility of knowing about all the subsequent types which Barf may use from Barf and onto their downstream descends (i.e. I know about "Bar", but may not know about "Foo").  Or perhaps I modify the inheritance change where `Bar : Foo1` and `Foo1 : Foo`.

If each class were responsible for knowing what it's own constituent types are, then I can localize any changes without having to go change any upstream classes.

Initially I thought about doing a static interface where each class defined it's known types, but alas that is not available to me.  So the question is how do I implement a design where I can pass in a type to a method, and each type knows what embedded types they use (there's no need to descent/list "native" types), and this `List<Type>` definition can be recursively descended....

Comment: You could [get the list of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710156/using-reflection-to-get-values-from-properties-from-a-list-of-a-class) of the class and loop that list to get the types.

Comment: Not sure this would be sufficient because how would a property know about the class inheritance?

Comment: I'm not sure I get this question... So at compile time you want to know where all possible implementations / abstractions and inheritable classes might be? So Forexample, Barf should show Bar, Foo, and a theoretical IFoo as well?

Comment: You can [get the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524562/getting-parent-class-name-using-reflection) with reflection.